# Python Tkinter, Number of Label/Entry based on IntVar

Tags: python, tkinter, label, tkinter-entry

I was hoping someone could help me with something. I would like to make an Tkinter app that asks for a number then uses that number to draw the correct number of Labels and Entrys.

Here's basic brainstorm of what I'm trying to do (I know this is wrong)

```
from Tkinter import *

root = Tk()

numlines = IntVar()

Label(root, text='Number Of Lines').grid(row=0, column=0) #this is to always stay 
Entry(root, textvariable=numlines).grid(row=0, column=1) #this is to stay always stay 
Button(root, text='Apply Number', command=apply).grid(row=1, column=1)

def apply():
    # this part to draw as a block based in numline(if munlines 5 then draw these two widget 5 times on 5 rows)
    Label(root, text='Line 1').grid(row=2, column=0)# this part to draw as a block based in numline(if munlines 5 then draw these two widget 5 times)
    Entry(root, textvariable=numlines).grid(row=2, column=1)

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Realistically all Tkinter applications should be put inside of a class. In addition it is also general a bad idea for use `import *` from any package as you could have override issues with unknown values that you imported. As such, the following example is inside of a class and should give you an idea of how this would look. I believe this is what you're looking for:

```
import Tkinter as Tk

class App(Tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master, *args, **kwargs):
        Tk.Frame.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        self.existing_lines = 2
        self.entry_lines = Tk.IntVar()

        Tk.Label(self, text="Number Of Lines").grid(row=0, column=0)
        Tk.Entry(self, textvariable=self.entry_lines).grid(row=0, column=1)
        Tk.Button(self, text="Apply Number", command=self.add_rows).grid(row=1, column=1)

    def add_rows(self):
        for row in xrange(self.existing_lines, self.existing_lines+self.entry_lines.get()):
            Tk.Label(self, text="Line %i" % (row-1)).grid(row=row, column=0)
            Tk.Entry(self, textvariable=self.entry_lines).grid(row=row, column=1)
            self.existing_lines+= 1

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = Tk.Tk()
    App(root).pack()
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: This is fantastic, Thanks very much, this is exactly what I need. Point taken about importing *, I do normally use Tkinter as Tk, Is just for small app i dont bother but i shall start doing it this way from now on.

Take Care

Again Thank you very much for your time and help, it is very much appreciated.

Comment: You are assigning the same (IntVar) textvariable to every `Entry`, so what you type in one of the Entries ends up in all of them. Consider making a list of `StringVar`s to use in the new Entries.

Comment: @fhdrsdg That's what the OP chose to do in his explanation. I assume he wanted it that way so you could enter the number of lines you wanted on any line and then hit enter.

Comment: @Thimble Ok that makes sense. I had interpreted it as a mistake in his code, because I don't really see the practical use of many Entries which all contain the same text.